# Why is my onchange event happening at page load, not when even triggers?

Tags: javascript

I have a div in my HTML that I want to add innerHTML to, but only when a user enters something in a text input. It is adding the innerHTML as soon as the page loads, so I guess I don't understand onchange event listening as well as I thought.

HTML:

```
<body>
<label for="changeMe">What is your favorite number?</label>
<input type="text" id="changeMe" />
<div id="addStuff"></div>

<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function doStuff() {
    var thing = document.getElementById("changeMe");
    thing.addEventListener('onchange', doMoreStuff());
}

function doMoreStuff() {
    var addStuff = document.getElementById("addStuff");
    var stuff = "<input 'type=text' />";
    addStuff.innerHTML = stuff;
}

window.onload = function() {
    doStuff();
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you are binding the result of `doMoreStuff()` with event handler.

*Use*

```
thing.addEventListener('change', doMoreStuff); //Notice remove () here
```

instead of

```
thing.addEventListener('onchange', doMoreStuff());
```

Comment: Or even better, `thing.addEventListener('change', doMoreStuff);`

Answer (score 2):

Right now you're *calling* the function when trying to bind the event handler, instead of passing the function.

You're also passing 'onchange', which is the name of the callback property, instead of 'change', which is the type of the event. See [the documentation of addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Change

```
thing.addEventListener('onchange', doMoreStuff());
```

to

```
thing.addEventListener('change', doMoreStuff);
```